# Upgrade php 5.5.9 to php 5.6.4

Tags: upgrade, apache2, php

`php -v` shows me this

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (cli) (built: Jul 28 2016 19:31:33) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

I want to upgrade it to php 5.6.4

I am not sure for the solutions i found who had php 5.5.9deb versions.

Comment: what makes you not sure about the solutions you found ? Please give more details to give you a better answer to your question.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that what i am doing is not just copy and paste but understanding the reason for it.

Answer (score 18):

Found the answer [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html):

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip
php -v
```

Comment: verified working as of star date: 2016 december 12

Comment: I did this and the final command output: PHP 5.6.30-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) not 5.6.4

Comment: Verified today: Ubuntu 14.04, php 5.5.4 > 5.6.30-7

Comment: The reference link is not pointing to a working page.